# Pester custom error text

Tags: powershell, pester

Does anyone know if Pester supports custom error texts?

Lets say I've the following test:

```
Describe "Get-HelloWorld" {
    It "outputs 'Hello world!'" {
        Get-HelloWorld | Should Be 'Hello world!'
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can set some custom error message if `Get-HelloWorld` returns another string than "Hello World"?

Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest version of Pester supports `-Because` where you can add some custom text that explains the purpose of the test.